# HTML/CSS One page website scrolling only certain divs

Tags: html, css

So i'm trying to create a website which simulates multiple hyperlinks, while holding the fixed content around the outside.

So far I have this for my Main webpage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS-JS/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="banner" class='page-padding'>
            <div id="in-page-nav">
                    <a href="#about">About</a>
                    <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                    <a href="#contact">Contact</a> 
            </div>
        </div>    

    <div id="persistentNav" onmouseover="this.id='persistentNavHover';" onmouseout="this.id='persistentNav';">

    <ul id="leftNav">
        <li><a class="nav" href="#Home">Homepage</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav" href="#Article1">Article 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav" href="#Article2">Article 2</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav" href="#Article3">Article 3</a></li>
    </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="page1-background">

            <div id="page1">
                    <a name="about"></a>
                    <div class="page-padding"></div>
                    <p>Article One</p>
            </div> <!--END page1-->
    </div>

    <div id="page-wrap">
            <div id="page2">
                    <a name="portfolio"></a>
                    <div class="page-padding"></div>
                    <p>Article 2</p>
                    <video width="100%" height="240" controls>
                        <source src="" type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                    </video>
            </div> <!--END page2-->

            <div id="page3">
                    <a name="contact"></a> 
                    <div class="page-padding"></div>
                    <p>Article</p>
                    <div id="wizards">

                    <ul>
                            <li><a href="images/dumbledore.jpg"><img src="images/dumbledore-sm.jpg" alt="Dumbledore" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="images/merlin.jpg"><img src="images/merlin-sm.jpg" alt="Merlin" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="images/gandalf.jpg"><img src="images/gandalf-sm.jpg" alt="Gandalf" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="images/harry-potter.jpg"><img src="images/harry-potter-sm.jpg" alt="Harry Potter" /></a></li>
                    </ul>

            </div>
            </div> <!--END page3-->

    </div> <!--END page-wrap-->    

    <div id="footer">
    <div id="none">
        <a href="#about">Footer</a>
        <a href="#portfolio">Footer</a>
        <a href="#contact">Footer</a> 
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this as my CSS file

```
/* 
    Document   : main
    Created on : 19-Mar-2014, 11:16:27
    Author     : dan
    Description:
        Purpose of the stylesheet follows.
*/
*{ margin:0 auto;}

body {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    font-family:georgia, times, serif; 
    height:2000px;
    }

#banner {
        position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0%;
        right:0px;
    background: white; 
    height:250px; 
    width:1000px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        }

#nav {
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-top:10px;
    word-spacing:20px;
}

#in-page-nav {
        text-align: center;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-top:45px;
    word-spacing:20px;
}

#page1-background {
    height: 1100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('Pictures/Middle-earth-Shadow-of-Mordor-7.jpg') no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%, 100%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    }

#page1 {
    height:1100px;
    width:1000px;
    background:#afc9ff;
    padding-top:250px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }

#page2 {
    height:1100px;
    width:1000px;
    background:#777cdc;
    padding-top:150px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }

#page3 {
    height:1100px;
    width:1000px;
    background:#9b70c0;
    padding-top:150px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }

#footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:#666; 
    height:70px; 
    width:100%;
    }

.page-padding {height:90px; width:100%;}


#persistentNav {
width: 250px;
position: fixed;
left: -250px;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transition: ease 0.3s;
-moz-transition: ease 0.3s;
-o-transition: ease 0.3s;
-ms-transition: ease 0.3s;
transition: ease 0.3s;
margin-top: -245px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
z-index: 900;
}

#persistentNavHover {
width: 250px;
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -245px;
-webkit-transition: ease 0.3s;
-moz-transition: ease 0.3s;
-o-transition: ease 0.3s;
-ms-transition: ease 0.3s;
transition: ease 0.3s;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
z-index: 900;
}

ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}

ul {
list-style: none;
}

#leftNav li a {
color: #888;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
width: 266px;
height: 24px;
padding-left: 24px;
padding-top: 15px;
display: block;
border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
border-right: 1px solid #222;
letter-spacing: 0.10em;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: left;
overflow: hidden;
zoom: 1;
-webkit-transition: ease 0.3s;
-moz-transition: ease 0.3s;
-o-transition: ease 0.3s;
-ms-transition: ease 0.3s;
transition: ease 0.3s;
}

#nav {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'FontSiteSansCondensed', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}
```

If you compile it, you'll see i have 3 articles following on from eachother, currently each 1100px tall with links to each. What i want to know is, if i press a link it will take me to the appropriate article (which i can do), but when i scroll within that article i will see the top of the top of the article to the bottom of the bottom of the article while scrolling but no more.

An example. If i select article 1, which is 1500px tall, and my screen is 1200px tall, there will be ~300px i'm not seeing. There are also 2 other articles. I want to scroll from the top of article one, to the bottom to view the other 300px of article WITHOUT overlapping onto article 2.

(i'm aware there are other issues with my code, but it works and the issues are mainly mismatching text-links, ignore them as I will fix them as i continue developing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add javascript to hide `#page2` and `page3` DIV when `article1` is clicked, and so on..

```
<li><a class="nav" href="#Article1" onclick="selectArticle1()">Article 1</a></li>
```

.

```
function selectArticle1(){
  document.getElementById('page1').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('page2').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('page3').style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Having added this, it does not shrink the page down to the height of the selected element. So the page is still 3000 or so pixels tall but now with lots of white space, so if the first article is selected the other two articles are white space instead. Any idea how when i select which div to display, how to grab the height of the page and limit the scrolling to the selected window (so you don't see the empty divs)?

Comment: remove `height: 1100px;` in #page1-background, then the height will be dynamic

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. Now i have to work out how to make the displayed screen/'page' the height of the users screen.